# Access issue to view the Kubernetes resources(namespaces, workloads, etc) from the azure portal

Tags: kubernetes, azure-active-directory, terraform, azure-aks

I've created the AKS cluster in Azure using Terraform with Azure RBAC enabled with AAD group. This AAD group has Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin role assigned to it. Also, users in his group have global admin access.

The issue is I can't see the Kubernetes resources. I'm getting `"Unable to reach the api server 'https://5545dd5555hj555dd55jkl8555589d-priv.portal.hcp.canadacentral.azmk8s.io'` or

```
 api server is too busy to respond. Check your network settings and refresh to try again."
```

I also have other clusters created manually and am able to see Kub resources from the portal. Note that I have the same permissions on every AKS cluster. I'm not sure what this error is trying to say or what the workaround is to see Kubernetes resources from azure portal. The AAD users for this cluster do have access to the Kub resources via kubctl.

Any lead would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have enabled Azure AD to the Kubernetes cluster :

```
data "azuread_application" "example" {
  display_name = "kavyarepoapp"
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "example" {
  application_id = data.azuread_application.example.application_id
}

# AKS cluster
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  name                = "mykaaks-cluster"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix          = "my-aks-cluster"
  kubernetes_version  = "1.25.5"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  # Azure AD integration
  service_principal {
    client_id     = data.azuread_application.example.application_id
    client_secret = var.client_secret
  }

  role_based_access_control_enabled = true
     tags = {
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}
```

Set the correct role and role binds: [Set the correct roles and role bindings | Microsoft-learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/user-cannot-get-cluster-resources)

[image]

I created an azure group assigned, user to it directory reader role.
I gave **Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin** role to the user who is logged in or group and App associated with it.

[image]

Then run the server nodes.

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group  <rg>  --name mykavyakscluster


kubectl get nodes --kubeconfig=<path-to-kubeconfig-file>
```

Could access the api successfully:

[image]

```
Merged "clustername" as current context in /home/saraboju/.kube/config
kubectl get nodes --kubeconfig=/home/saraboju/.kube/config
NAME                              STATUS   ROLES   AGE   VERSION
aks-default-xxx   Ready    agent   12m   v1.25.5
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/managed-aad

Comment: earlier I had my AAD group attached to Azure Kubernetes Service Contributor Role. but the users in this group have global admin role. so they should be able to see kub resources from portal. I've also assigned Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin role to my AAD group as you mentioned. I still can't see resources from portal.

Comment: The role creation may take sometime and also check the Application has this role , cluster> IAM>role assignment>here add Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin role to user ,application or group .

Comment: Okay I updated my answer as well as gave the role to AAD group, as you mentioned. still, the issue persists. What I'm interested in knowing is what this error means, and in what circumstances should I get this error.

Comment: Have you got chance to go through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/troubleshoot-cluster-connection-issues-api-server) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/client-ip-address-cannot-access-api-server).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/user-cannot-get-cluster-resources